# IOS/Objective-C: Reduce file size of pngs for thumbnails

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I allow users to take a profile pic and then I need to upload it to the server.  The iPhone pics are large in file size...much larger than needed for a profile pic and they take up a lot of space on the phone and also take a long time to upload to the server.  I'm finding that on occasion if there is a weak Internet connection, the server times out half way through the upload.

I have code in a category to decrease the height and width of the image size but it does not seem to decrease the actual file size.

Can anyone suggest a lite way to do this--ideally without using a heavy library.  Also, I'd like to avoid converting to jpg which I know allows for lossy compression.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

The problem might also be with how I work with the thumbnail after creating it below so I a including that code as well.

Here is code I am using to decrease height and width but it does not appear to reduce size in bytes.

```
@implementation UIImage (Thumbnail)
-(UIImage *) createThumbnailToFillSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGSize mainImageSize = size;
    UIImage *thumb;

    CGFloat widthScaler = size.width / mainImageSize.width;
    CGFloat heightScaler = size.height / mainImageSize.height;

    CGSize repositionedMainImageSize = mainImageSize;

    CGFloat scaleFactor;
    // Determine if we should shrink based on width or hight
    if(widthScaler > heightScaler)
    {
        // calculate based on width scaler
        scaleFactor = widthScaler;
        repositionedMainImageSize.height = ceil(size.height / scaleFactor);
    }
    else {
        // calculate based on height scaler
        scaleFactor = heightScaler;
        repositionedMainImageSize.width = ceil(size.width / heightScaler);
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGFloat xInc = ((repositionedMainImageSize.width-mainImageSize.width) / 2.f) *scaleFactor;
    CGFloat yInc = ((repositionedMainImageSize.height-mainImageSize.height) / 2.f) *scaleFactor;

    [self drawInRect:CGRectMake(xInc, yInc, mainImageSize.width * scaleFactor, mainImageSize.height * scaleFactor)];
    thumb = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


    return thumb;
}



   //Display image in viewdidload by calling above method:

      UIImage *chosenImage = [self loadImageNamed:picname];
            CGFloat side = 150;
            side *=[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            UIImage *thumbnail = [chosenImage createThumbnailToFillSize:CGSizeMake(side, side)];
            self.imageView.image = thumbnail;


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.didChange=YES;
      self.imageWasPicked = YES;//this is a dupe but used for updateButton
    self.changedPic=YES;
    [self updateSaveButton];

    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
//Should I be putting code to make thumbnail here instead of in display?

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Comment: Have you actually checked the size of the resulting image (both in pixels and in bytes, once converted to whichever format your want)? Also what format are you converting to? JPEG is lossy, but with a decent quality factor you won't notice it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using UIImagePickerController in order to let the user choose a picture, make sure that you set

```
theImagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
```

This should already decrease the size of final image by 10-15 times.

If the received image is still too big, then [here](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) you can find some good examples of image resizing.

Comment: One question.  Is it possible to set .allowsediting to YES and also skip step where it asks you "use photo"?

Comment: Do you mean the screen with two buttons -- "Cancel" and "Choose Photo"? I don't think it is possible. The screen is for the user to choose an appropriate part (square?) of an image.